# Probability of two RVs being equal

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$~Binom($n,1/2$) and $Y$~Binom($m,1/2$) be independent. Calculate $P(X=Y)$.

My attempt:

Assume $m\le n$
$$P(X=Y)=\sum_{k=0,\ldots,m} P(X=k)P(Y=k)=(\frac{1}{2})^{n+m} \sum_{k=0,\ldots,m}{n \choose k}{m \choose k}$$

I have no idea how can I move further. Any ideas?

Comment: By $X$~Binom(n,1/2) do you mean that $X$ is a random variable with binomial distribution of $n$ trials and probability $p=1/2$ of success on each trial?

Comment: You are almost there. The thing on the RHS already looks somewhat like a convolution. Robert Israel shows you how to rewrite $X - Y$ so that it becomes sum of two binomial variables + constant. Look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Sums_of_binomials

Comment: Yes Rory, exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $X - Y = X + Z - m$ where $Z = m - Y$.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I dont get it how it helps... Thank you

Comment: but whatis the distribution of $Z$ then?

Comment: @ad233: if $Y$ is the number of "successes", $Z$ is the number of "failures".  So that's also binomial, with parameters ...

Comment: I don't see how it has also binomial  distribution

Comment: You do notice that $m$ is the number of trials for $Y$, right?

Comment: One person's failures are another's successes.